# Unable to access any widgets in an window

Tags: gtk

I have one GtkWindow with one GtkVBox and GtkEntry.
Some times it happens that i am unable to access buttons Buttons, lists, entries.
But i am able to add widgets to GtkVBox and it gets updated with new widgets too.

Looks like it loses Focus. i tries with setting focus but it does not helps.

What might be wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? Are the widgets not responding to mouse/keyboard input?

Comment: Yes Widgets are not responding to mouse and key events.
I can see Cursor blinking in Text filed but not able to type into it.

Comment: Are you running the GTK+ loop as normal? Any idle or timer handlers that might be taking all the execution time? Is your process showing signs of running with a high CPU load?

Comment: I am using glib timer in one place, but it in not active all the time. I used it for destroying one time based pop-up window. I display one pop-up for 5 secs and then destroys pop-up and timer, this pop-up get displayed on this top level window. Is this timer and pop-up is causing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention having a pop-up, in a comment. Is this pop-up modal, are you nesting calls to `gtk_main()`, or calling `gtk_dialog_run()`?

It sounds a bit as if GTK+ is considering the displayed UI to be "locked", which it also does when a modal dialog is open.

Try it without your timer and pop-up, see if it changes.

Comment: Pop-up is model type, i am not using any nesting calls to `gtk_main`. i am destroying pop-up when timer expires. if gtk locks any window then how should we unlock it?